# Select using LIKE between 2 ranges in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, between, sql-like

I'm trying to get all the values out of a database table between 2 different dates.  The problem is my date column contains dates as a string in the format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM'(i.e. 9/13/2012 13:15, 10/14/2012 22:32, 11/8/2012 12:10 etc).  I am able to use a SELECT and LIKE query to get all the rows that contain whatever date string is passed in, by itself, but I need to select all the rows between a certain range (like between 9/13/2012 and 9/15/2012).  Do I need to do a conversion to a date format to make this work?

This is the code that is working by inputting one date:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE data_time RLIKE '^$date_range1'");
```

but I need to select between 2 dates.  I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE data_time RLIKE BETWEEN '^$date_range1%' and '^$date_range2%");
```

Comment: That is a dangerous way of performing queries. You might look into mysqli and prepared queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to convert the dates to a `date` or `datetime` type.

Otherwise the ordering will not work: as text, "11/02/2012" comes before "12/03/1901", since "11" is less than "12".

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. Convert your field date_time to DATETIME type!

Create new field `data_time_copy` in `data` table, and run next query:

```sql
# field d is alias for your date_time
UPDATE data
SET date_time_copy = CONCAT(
                         SUBSTRING(d,7,4), '-', SUBSTRING(d,1,2), '-', SUBSTRING(d,4,2), 
                         ' ', SUBSTRING(d,12,5), ':00'
                     )
```

Then remove your field `date_time`, and rename `date_time_copy` to `date_time`. And fix your code.

#### 2. If you cannot change field type to DATETIME, use this lame solution (overkill)

```sql
# field d is alias for your date_time
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE 
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(d,7,4), '-', SUBSTRING(d,1,2), '-', SUBSTRING(d,4,2)) 
    BETWEEN '2012-09-13' AND '2013-09-15'
```

Comment: If you run formulas on your data columns, the engine can't use indexes.

Comment: @AlainCollins: First solution is to fix his table field to datetime type, where indexes (if set) will work super! But if he doesn't want first solution, then he has the second solution that is "lame" and "overkill", like I already wrote. What is wrong with my answer?